# High specific energy solid material for cryogenic work

Tags: physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

I would like to know a few (solid) materials that have a very high heat capacity (specific heat?) that can absorb cold energy very well, and hold that cold for quite a while from 77K to 90K (at least 5 hours)

I am using a high tech stirling heat pump to cool down superconductors (along with very good insulation around the superconductors) to 77K. But I want to put that material around/on the superconductors, to maximise the time they stay cold. I would hold the heat pump against the material for perhaps 30 mins, and cool-down that material. Having an ability hold "cold energy" very well, and not release it too easily, would be needed. The material would need to handle cryogenic temps very well and not expand/contract too much (hence desire for a solid). That material would probably be inside a 2mm walled copper box (with superconductors strapped to the outside of that box)

Comment: The amount of heat it loses depends on the value of the exposed area of the solid. You can also protect the heat by polishing the surface, this reduces it's emissivity. By the way welcome to Chem SE.

Comment: cold energy????

Comment: You are looking for a thing which is simply not there. Heat capacity of ***anything*** is pitifully low when compared to the heat of phase transitions, especially boiling. This is the reason why we use liquid nitrogen for cooling in the first place.